# how to convert php array to xml

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I have php array like below

```
$row = array (
  'name' => 'david',
 'bio' => 'good man'
 );
```

i want to convert this array to corresponding XML page like scenario below.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <note>
   <name>david</name>
   <bio>good man</bio>
</note>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked up methods of creating XML using PHP?

Comment: i want to the php array get output like <note>
   <name>david</name>
   <bio>good man</bio>
</note>

Comment: I think this answer will make your life easier :D 

[http://stackoverflow.com/a/5965940/2178259](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5965940/2178259)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this.

```
   $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<note/>');
   $row = array_flip($row);
   array_walk_recursive($row, array ($xml, 'addChild'));
   echo htmlentities($xml->asXML());
```

Comment: use `echo htmlentities($xml->asXML());` to see the markup, this is the correct answer, +1

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<root><blub>bla</blub><bar>foo</bar></root>
but can i get it in output like this.

Comment: thabk you Ghost. Its Working

Comment: thanks, Ghost for your help. I am updating this answer as well

Comment: hi ghost are you there

Comment: the value of array is displayed as a xml tag & key of array displayed as value of tag

Comment: @Jishad, have you added `$row = array_flip($row);` before array_walk?

Comment: Hi Ram, How can i remove the &#xD; character from source code..pls help

Answer (score 0):

Generate XML with DOM:

```
$row = array (
  'name' => 'david',
  'bio' => 'good man'
);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->formatOutput = TRUE;

$note = $dom->appendChild($dom->createElement('note'));
foreach ($row as $name => $value) {
  $note
    ->appendChild($dom->createElement($name))
    ->appendChild($dom->createTextNode($value));
}

echo $dom->saveXml();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<note>
  <name>david</name>
  <bio>good man</bio>
</note>
```